# Can I take my mini-pig to the beach?

Tags: travel, pig

I have [a young mini-pig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnbHD.jpg) (he'll be about 8 months old when we're thinking of doing this). We're looking at taking a vacation in the future that would give us a chance to take him for walks on the beach. However, we're a little worried.

I know that [sodium can be deadly for pigs](https://americanminipigassociation.com/mini-pig-health/salt-toxicity-in-mini-pigs/). And what place has more sodium than the beach and ocean?! Our little guy *loves* to root everything, so I wouldn't be surprised if he ends up swallowing some dirt and water--which I know will be chalk full with salt.

Will this be alright for him at 8 months? Or is it a better idea to avoid the beach entirely? Is there an age we should wait for to take him to something like this?

Comment: https://www.minipigs4sale.com/9-Tips-on-How-to-Care-For-a-Pig.html

Comment: I linked it because it does mention summer tips including "Cool ocean water is tempting to your pig. Do not allow her to drink too much sea water. Salt in the water will make her sick." which seems to imply the beach is okay as long as you keep a careful eye on it.

Comment: Your source for salt poisoning describes all cases of accidentally eaten high amounts of salt, or products that smells/tastes good and have a high amount of salt. It is like a child, which swallows a lot of baking soda or such in one part. Or eats the well smelling modeling clay. I think your pig (like a child) do not finds salt, or salted water tasty and drinks a lot of it. A second reason (according to the source) is no fresh water available. But on the beach you would bring for you and your pet water with you, or make a break to go somewhere to drink something :-)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, it's not contact with the salt that is dangerous to them, it is ingesting it. I'm pretty sure they have the sense to not drink enough of the sea water to do damage.

I've never heard of pigs coming to harm due to proximity to the ocean. In fact, there is an island in the Bahamas that is home to pigs that swim in the ocean with tourists (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Beach).

There are some things that I'd be concerned about. Such as laws which would prevent pigs on the beach. Or the piggy having adequate protection from the sun, and access to fresh water.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but it's not his proximity to large amounts of salt I'm worried about. It's the fact that--being a pig--he loves to stick his nose and mouth into everything he can to take a test taste. I have heard of the pig beach (and in fact many of them have died from ingesting sand!), but I'm curious how this will be for a pig whose never been before (as opposed to those that have clearly acclimated to the tropically lifestyle)